# Assigning a score to a random variable selected by a user who was given two options from a list through random.choice()

Tags: python

I am trying to write a script that allows me to rank things that are subjective like 'which person I like best' from a list of people, by presenting myself with a series of A/B tests of 2 people selected from the list at random. Then I need to count each 'win' toward that persons score so I can rank the people at the end.

So far I have:

```
mark = 0
john = 0
matt = 0
dave = 0
will = 0
alex = 0
kyle = 0 
sean = 0
greg = 0
mike = 0

friends = ['mark', 'john', 'matt','dave','will','alex','kyle','sean','greg','mike']
pick = 0
while (pick!='Q'):
    A = (random.choice(friends))
    B = (random.choice(friends))
    pick = input('Who is your first pick: A for {}, B for {}:'.format(A,B))
    if pick == 'A':
        matt += 1
    elif pick == 'B':
        john += 1
    elif pick =='Q':
        print('Please see your results.')
        break
    else:
        print('Please enter A, B or Q to quit:')
```

This works, but it assigns all scores to matt or john because I don't know how to assign the score to the specific random variable that was selected that time around. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/dLM76Kh7

Comment: https://www.codevscolor.com/python-index-method-get-index-list/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel   I don't think that's the best answer for a newbie necessarily